# transition from A image to B image with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an `UIImageView` of an white color arrow image. I am animating it to rotate 90 degree's. I also want that `UIImageView` to change to a black color arrow image as it rotates.

The only solution I can think of is to stack the two images on top of each other, animate both when ever it rotates and change the white color arrow image's alpha (so it fades in and out).

Is there a simpler way to obtain this effect?

Is there a build in transition effect to fade one image out and another image in?

Comment: That drafted way would be the way to go.

Comment: What is complex about your solution?

Comment: i'm just seeing if there is something built in that would accomplish the same effect. i haven't worked a lot with animations yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a good grasp of what to do. Probably the easiest repeatable way to do this is to create a `UIView` subclass and add both of your arrows to it. Then add a couple of functions like these.

```
-(void)rotate90{
    blackArrow.alpha = 0;
    [self bringSubviewToFront:blackArrow];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        blackArrow.alpha = 1;
        blackArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        whiteArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    }];
}
-(void)rotate0{
    whiteArrow.alpha = 0;
    [self bringSubviewToFront:whiteArrow];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        whiteArrow.alpha = 1;
        blackArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        whiteArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }];
}
```